# How could the mobile Apple.com menu button animation be recreated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before I start, I'd like to state I don't plan on using this animation for anything. I just think it's cool and want to see how it works.

Ever been to apple.com? Most people have, and some on their phone. If you have, you would've seen the mobile site - it uses a slide down navigation bar with some cool animations. But how could this be recreated? The navigation bar itself could easily be recreated with a inverted box-shadow, but how do I get those two images (or in this case divs, if possible) to animation like shown [here](http://gyazo.com/6d1088a691a8aad8b8e657f24a1bc858)?

Comment: well, you can see that it is two lines rearranging in such a way as to create a cross, so to do this, you will need css3 animations, there are tons of tutorials on this, try something and report back :)

Comment: @epoch This is what I came up with, from what I can tell, it should work, yet it doesn't. When I move the transform the default class it works, so I would assume it has to do with my poor JS. http://jsfiddle.net/xujvhb0d/

Comment: I tried it myself for a short while with no success, seems a bit tricky, I suggest putting a bounty on it and hopefully someone with more experience with animations can help :)

Comment: @epoch Unfortunately, I don't have enough for a bounty - oh well. It was worth a shot. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's an open source plugin, but I forget its name and can't find it again... But I'm sure that I found a demo like that before...

Answer (score 0):

Its done by CSS3 animations. Like transform and transition.